# Is there a source for OTC Vitamin ingredients?

Tags: products, barcodes

The FDA site doesn't have much on Over The Counter (OTC) vitamin ingredients/strengths. 
I know there are a few sources out there that charge quite a bit. 
I'm trying to match UPCs with their individual ingredients and strengths. 
Anyone know of a source?